# \rotatebox error with prebreak in \lstlisting

Tags: listings, rotating, fragile

Command `\rotatebox` generates error when used with non-orthogonal (not a multiple of 90) angles in `prebreak` of a `\lstlisting`.
Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, listings}
%\usepackage{makerobust}
%\MakeRobustCommand\rotatebox

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  language={}, basicstyle=\ttfamily, frame=single,
  breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=true,
  prebreak=\mbox{\space\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$<$}}
% prebreak=\mbox{\space\protect\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$<$}}
]
abcd00 efgh01 ijkl02 mnop03 qrst04 uvwx05 yzab06 cdef07 ghij08 klmn09 opqr10 stuv11 wxyz12 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The generated error is:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                   \kern
l.13 abcd00
            efgh01 ijkl02 mnop03 qrst04 uvwx05 yzab06 cdef07 ghij08 klmn09 o...
```

As you might have noticed the comments, I already know that `\rotatebox` is fragile and have tried both `\protect` and `\MakeRobustCommand` but none of them solves the problem. An interesting observation is that the command works when the given rotation angle is a multiple of 90.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `listings` redefines `\space` for typesetting the code internally, but `\rotatebox` relies on the original definition. `\rotatebox` has to do some trigonometric calculation, depending on the passed degree, so the error only pops up for non-trivial rotation values.

An easy fix is to restore the original `\space` definition locally before using `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  language={}, basicstyle=\ttfamily, frame=single,
  breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=true,
  prebreak=\mbox{\space\def\space{ }\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$<$}}
]
abcd00 efgh01 ijkl02 mnop03 qrst04 uvwx05 yzab06 cdef07 ghij08 klmn09 opqr10 stuv11 wxyz12 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

outputs

> [image]